# How to implement a specific data interpretation?

Tags: date, filter, return, point, stock

I am trying to use data from a specific date in a large data set, creating a single value to use in a diff function in order to subtract points on the return column from each other at different dates. For example, I would like to use **11/9/2007** and get the result of **5.205863e-03** and then subtract that from the return on **11/12/2007**.

```
        date      return
1     11/8/2007 -2.651996e-02
2     11/9/2007 -5.205863e-03
3    11/12/2007 -9.491706e-03
```

I tried using a filter but it does not seem to be working.

```
 df <- data.frame(x=date,freq=return_gspc)

  df$freq[ds$x=="12/23/2009"]

  return <- filter(date_return,date=="11/9/2007")
```

How can I implement this?